# Eclipse: JRE System Library Selection - Execution Environment vs Alternate JRE

Tags: java, eclipse

I am configuring my build path such that one of my Eclipse projects uses a different JRE than my workspace default.  In the JRE System Library window, I am presented with 3 options...

[image]

I know I don't want to use my workspace default, but the Execution Environment and Alternate JRE both allow me to choose my jdk1.8.0_20. What's the difference between the Execution Environment and the Alternate JRE options? Does it matter which one I choose?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Execution Environment specifies a type of JRE without specifying exactly which JRE you want to use.

You specify the JRE used for the Execution Environment in the 'Preferences > Java > Installed JREs > Execution Environments' preference page. You could, for example, change the JavaSE-1.8 Execution Environment to use the JDK 1.8.0 update 25 (instead of update 20) without having the change the JRE name in all the places in your projects that use a JRE.

Answer (score 0):

Execution environment combo, allows you to select profile, like CDC (Connected Deveice Configuration), OSGi, etc.